# How to read list<T> from the end-user's side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, signalr.client

how to read a list sent using sockets in from the end-user's side ?

I've tried this

```
var lstA = $('<div />').text(listASServer).html();
$('#listA').empty();
$('#listA').append(lstA[0].id);
$('#listA').append(lstA[1].id);
$('#listA').append(lstA[2].id);
$('#listA').append(lstA[3].id);
$('#listA').append(lstA[4].id);
```

Knowing that `listASServer` is the server's sent list.

Comment: Have you tried to examine the bare response received by the browser?

Comment: @Pino, I didn't. Can you tell me how please ?

Comment: There are a lot of tools, for example the ones built in modern browsers, but my favourite is Firebug for Firefox.